# Determining the First Digit

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am trying to determine if the first character in the string starts with a specific character. 
Like:

```
number = raw_input('What is your answer?')
if number == '0':
    #Put in my code#
    pass
```

In this case, I want to find out whether the `number`'s string starts with `0`. Is there a built-in function from python that can determine whether the string starts with a specific character? DO I have to use `split()` to figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string.

Strings are never equal to numbers.

```
>>> '0' == 0
False
```

Compare the string with a string. For example, to check whether the string starts with specific character (sub-string), using [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
if number.startswith('0'):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inputing a string when you do

```
number = raw_input('What is your answer?')
```

so You can check first element like

```
number = raw_input('What is your answer?')
try:
    if number[0]=='0':
        print "First element is 0"
        #Put your code
    else:
        print "First element is not 0"
        #Do something else
except IndexError:
    print "Input was null"
```